# PHP Excel to use Php variable to select conditional formating area

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I i have a phpexcel page with 2 worksheets and on one that is using condinal formatting and its pulling the data out of a database and i am wanting to use the row number in to select how far to place the conditional formatting so  i have this variable which is auto incremented to place the the data into each row

```
$rownumber++
```

then  i have this peice of code

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateConditionalStyle(
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I2')->getConditionalStyles(),
                'I2:K4'
            );
```

what i am wanting to do is where it has 
I2:K4 i want  it be something like this

I2:K$rownumber

so that uses the auto increasing row number to know how far to put the conditional formating but i have been unsuccesful in trying to get anything like this to work for me so if anyone has an idea how to do this please i need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range argument is just a standard PHP string, so you can use standard PHP string concatenation like 'I2:K'.$rownumber

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateConditionalStyle( 
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I2')->getConditionalStyles(), 
                'I2:K'.$rownumber  
            );
```